# Contour Plot from the result of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to get a contour plot using the following code but getting some errors. Showing NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable s^[Prime].

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
zeta = 2.0;
m = 10.0;
a = 0.5;
(*x=0.4;*)
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.2;
alpha = 0.2;
beta = 1.0;
k = 0.5;
F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);

sys1 = s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]];
iv1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
sol1[x_] := NDSolve[{sys1, iv1}, s, {y, 0, h}]

sys2 = p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*sol1[x]'[y] == 0;
iv2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};
sol2[x_] := NDSolve[{sys2, iv2}, p, {y, 0, h}]

ListContourPlot[
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[
    Evaluate[
     Table[{x, y, (s[y] /. sol2[x])[[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]], {y, 0, 
     1, 1/30}]], 3], FrameLabel -> {X, Y}]
```

while I am getting desired result using the following code for sys1.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"](*Clears all constans*)

lam = 5.0;
gma = 0.5;
zeta = 2.0;
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;(*x=0.4*)t = 0.2;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);

sys1 = {s''[
     y] == (lam/2.0)^2.0*(Sinh[
        4.0*s[y]]/(1.0 + 4.0*gma*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]))};

iv1 = {s[-h] == zeta, s[h] == zeta};

sol[x_] := NDSolve[Join[sys1, iv1], s, {y, -1, 1}]


ListContourPlot[
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[
    Evaluate[
     Table[{x, y, (s[y] /. sol[x])[[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]], {y, 0, 1,
      1/30}]], 3], FrameLabel -> {X, Y}]
```

Comment: If you look at the output of your code, you will see that `h` is expressed of terms of `x` which is not known quantity. Then you are using `h` for the range of solution for NDSolve. Hence `NDSolve` complains. I recommend you look at the output of each command before using in in later computation steps to make sure it  makes sense and correct to use.

Comment: But the same thing works only for sys1 as you can see from the edited question.

Comment: sys2 is a 4th order de, but iv2 does not give a 3rd order initial value.